# Activating the Square POS terminal from a non Square server

Tags: php, api, square-connect, square

Our online reservation service for sports venues includes online payments via Square. Our headache concerns OFFline payments. Our system allows bookings at the frontdesk. In those case online payment is not an option.

What we would like to do is that in such case our system (webserver) can send a signal to the (Square POS terminal) like: wake up, process payment of X $$. All the customer has to then is swipe his/her card.

Is there a way to do this???

Note: After reading the documentation I have a hunch that  the Square POS API could play  an important role. Is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, The point of Sale APi for web might be able to help you. Please review the documentation here: https://docs.connect.squareup.com/articles/web-api-ios